# How to make a primary scope and secondary scope on DHCP server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, dhcp

I am changing network structure and part of that is to change ip from 10.10.111.0 /24 to 172.16.0.0 /16 range.

Now I need to have DHCP ready first in 172.16 range.

I have two DHCP scope on a single DHCP server.

10.10.111.0

172.16.20.0

How can I make sure that users will get IP address from 172.16.20.0 scope mainly instead of 10.10.111.0 scope without deactivate 10.10.111.0 scope?

Is there a way to setup primary scope and secondary scope on DHCP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no concept of "primary scope" and "secondary scope" in Windows DHCP AFAIK. If you want the DHCP clients to get ip addressing from the new scope instead of the old scope then simply deactivate the old scope.

Assuming that the DHCP server and the DHCP clients are connected to the same physical network, the DHCP server will need an interface and ip address in the same subnet as the new scope.

Comment: Yeah, DHCP server must be in the same range of new netowrk. I need to change the IP on DHCP server first. or I guess I can setup IP Helper on my sonicwall. so x1 can get DHCP from x0

Comment: It is possible for Windows DHCP server to hand out addresses from different scopes based on vlan.